# "Invalid window handle" error when using FileOpenPicker from C++/WinRT without UWP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) to write something interesting. Having very little experience in Windows programming and no experience in C++/CX, I started out by trying [sample program (OCR)](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/10.0.16299.0/Samples/Ocr).

The sample program is about optical character recognition, I modified it to be face detector (console-based). It worked very well.

I want to convert getting file from command-line to file dialog, so I ported the following snippet [from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker):

```
  FileOpenPicker picker = FileOpenPicker();
  picker.ViewMode(PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
  picker.SuggestedStartLocation(PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary);
  picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".jpg");
  picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".jpeg");
  picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".png");

  StorageFile file = co_await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

No compile error, but when I run the program, I get this error message:

```
hresult_error: (0x80070578) Invalid window handle.
```

I think the error occurs because it is a console-based program (wmain), not wWinMain.

I tried to find a solution online, but they are all about UWP. Please provide a solution that does not involve UWP and must be able to compile from `cl.exe` directly.

**Note**:

According to [UWP APIs callable from a classic desktop app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt695951(v=vs.85).aspx), if an API has [DualApiPartitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.DualApiPartitionAttribute) attribute, it will work in classic desktop app, otherwise it won't. For example, [Geolocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator) has this attribute so it will work.

However, even though [FaceDetector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.faceanalysis.facedetector) does *not* have this attribute it still works proven in my toy program.

Anything from `Windows::UI` definitely requires UWP (although there is https://aka.ms/windowsui/inwin32). FileOpenPicker does not have this attribute but it is not under `Windows::UI`, so there might be a chance it can be workaround.

Complete code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")

#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Media.FaceAnalysis.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace std::chrono;

using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Pickers;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::Imaging;
using namespace Windows::Media::FaceAnalysis;

using Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector;

IAsyncOperation<int> AsyncSample() {
  FileOpenPicker picker = FileOpenPicker();
  picker.ViewMode(PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
  picker.SuggestedStartLocation(PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary);
  picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".jpg");
  picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".jpeg");
  picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".png");

  StorageFile file = co_await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
  //StorageFile file = co_await StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(
  //    L"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\20170318_202325.jpg");
  IRandomAccessStream stream = co_await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read);

  BitmapDecoder decoder = co_await BitmapDecoder::CreateAsync(stream);
  SoftwareBitmap bitmap = co_await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

  FaceDetector detector = co_await FaceDetector::CreateAsync();

  SoftwareBitmap converted =
      SoftwareBitmap::Convert(bitmap, BitmapPixelFormat::Nv12);

  IVector<DetectedFace> result = co_await detector.DetectFacesAsync(converted);
  printf("Detection done\n");
  for (auto& face : result) {
    BitmapBounds box = face.FaceBox();
    printf("[%u %u %u %u]\n", box.X, box.Y, box.Width, box.Height);
  }
  printf("Printing done\n");

  return 0;
}

int wmain() {
  init_apartment();

  try {
    int res = AsyncSample().get();
    printf("%d\n", res);
  } catch (hresult_error& e) {
    printf("hresult_error: (0x%8X) %ls\n", e.code(), e.message().c_str());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it requires Application View to work properly, just like most of UWP APIs dealing with UI?

Comment: `FileOpenPicker` is not under `Windows::UI`, so I was hoping I can avoid Application View. See my edited note above.

Comment: Use [IInitializeWithWindow](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190412-00/?p=102413).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! (Wohoo, the legendary Raymond Chen!)

Comment: hey how do I achieve the same with c#. I am having struggles doing it. the line of code which I added was this `picker.As<Windows.UI.Core.IInitializeWithCoreWindow>().Initialize(CoreWindow);`.

Comment: @JohnLondon Could you post an answer with your fixed version? Where did you get a HWND from to call that method?

Comment: @MHebes posted in answer

Answer (score 2):

So this was the modification neeeded:

```
IAsyncOperation<int> AsyncSample() {
  HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow(); // #include <windows.h>

  FileOpenPicker picker = FileOpenPicker();
  picker.as<IInitializeWithWindow>()->Initialize(hwnd);
```