# How do I display a C++/WinRT FileOpenPicker from an exe without a console or window?

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

From a C++ executable on windows, I want to display a [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker?view=winrt-22000).

To do this, I need a window to set as the object's owner:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/display-ui-objects#winui-3-with-c

But where do I get the HWND from? I need to call `Initialize`, but the docs assume you have a `hWnd` already:

```cpp
folderPicker.as<::IInitializeWithWindow>()->Initialize(hWnd);
```

My process does not always have a console window, so `::GetConsoleWindow()` will not work.

Here's what I have so far by attempting to use `CreateWindow`. Nothing happens.

```cpp
// clang-format off
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
#include <Windows.h>
// clang-format on

#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <system_error>

LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
      ::PostQuitMessage(0);
      return 0;
  }
  return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
  try {
    winrt::init_apartment();

    winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker openPicker;

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {sizeof(WNDCLASSEX),    CS_CLASSDC, WndProc, 0L,   0L,
                     GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL,       NULL,    NULL, NULL,
                     L"ImGui Example",      NULL};
    ::RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindow(
        wc.lpszClassName, L"Dear ImGui DirectX10 Example", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100, 1280, 800, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hwnd) {
      std::cerr
          << std::error_code(::GetLastError(), std::system_category()).message()
          << "\n";
      return 1;
    }

    openPicker.as<::IInitializeWithWindow>()->Initialize(hwnd);
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation(
        winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::PickerLocationId::Desktop);
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L"*");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".jpeg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".png");
    auto file = openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync().get();
    std::string str = winrt::to_string(file.Path());
    std::cout << "name: " << str << "\n";

    return 0;
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177961/invalid-window-handle-error-when-using-fileopenpicker-from-c-winrt-without-u) appears to be asking a similar thing, but OP solved it with `::GetConsoleWindow()`, which is not an option.

Comment: The answer was provided in a comment made by Raymond Chen, who also provided a link to the documentation.

Comment: @KenWhite indeed, but that documentation assumes you have a HWND from somewhere else. The OP of that question did not have one, which is the situation I’m also in.

Comment: The answer is in Raymond's comment; the OP of that question thanks Raymond for providing the solution in a comment that follows.

Comment: @MHebes you can probably just use [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) in this case. Otherwise, create your own `HWND` via `CreateWindow/Ex()`

Answer (score 1):

Based on empirical evidence, [`IInitializeWithWindow::Initialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iinitializewithwindow-initialize) is happy with just about any top-level window handle. A window handle associated with a process running in the CONSOLE subsystem is commonly available through the [`GetConsoleWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) API:

```cpp
openPicker.as<::IInitializeWithWindow>()->Initialize(::GetConsoleWindow());
```

This produces the desired behavior<sup>1</sup> when using the standard command prompt (hosted by *ConHost.exe*). Launching the same program from a process using a [pseudoconsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/pseudoconsoles) instead (such as [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/terminal)) things start to get flaky: The FilePicker does show up, but it no longer follows the rules of [owned windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows). It's hiding behind the host process' window, and doesn't move to the foreground, when the (not actually an) owner is activated.

Whether this is how things should work, or are designed to work, or if any of this is within specification is unclear. None of this is documented, which seems to be the most convenient way to ship interfaces these days.

The fact that [`FileOpenPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker) isn't documented to implement `IInitializeWithWindow` doesn't exactly help, either. All hail to *cloaked interfaces* of which there is only [anecdotal evidence](https://kennykerr.ca/2012/11/09/windows-8-whered-you-put-my-hwnd/).

Ranting aside, you'll probably want to use `std::wcout` in place of `std::cout`. Otherwise you'll see an address printed rather than a string.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Just because you can doesn't necessarily mean you [should create a window hierarchy across threads](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).*

Comment: The window you initialize with should belong to your process. This means that the console window is a bad choice, since it belongs to conhost, not you. Create a window, and use that window to initialize the picker. Note that the picker will not be modal to the console. You aren't meant to cross the streams like that. Console apps use the console. GUI apps use the GUI.

Answer (score -1):

```
    // 0. Header files: 
    // <windows.ui.xaml.window.h>
    // <ShObjIdl_core.h>

    // 1. Get Window HWND
    auto windowNative{ this->m_inner.as<::IWindowNative>() };
    HWND hWnd{ 0 };
    windowNative->get_WindowHandle(&hWnd); 

    // 2. Initialize folder picker 
    FolderPicker folderPicker{};
    folderPicker.as<::IInitializeWithWindow>()->Initialize(hWnd);
```

Comment: Wall of codes usually don't make good answers and are likely to be downvoted and removed. Provide some explanations on your code and solution to improve it.